# can't copy folder inside the folder

Tags: php

I've tried copy directory with this code:

```
$src = './resources/instansi/default/';
$dst = './resources/instansi/';

protected function copy_folder($src, $dst) {
    $dir = @opendir($src);
    @mkdir($dst);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                copy_folder($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file); 
            }
            else {
                copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
 closedir($dir); 
}
```

But I got fatal error : Call to undefined function copy_folder() . on line:

```
copy_folder($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
```

Can't copy folder inside of directory.

Maybe someone can help me? thanks.

Comment: What fatal do you get?
Could it be some permissions issue?

Comment: Call to undefined function copy_folder() @inneedofhelp

Answer (score 1):

Remove the prefixing "protected"

Answer (score 0):

If this code is just a snippet then you're inside the context of a class and you should call $this->copy_folder if you're not in the context of a class then you should remove the "protected" keyword

Comment: This code is in outside the context of a class, and I still got same error if I remove the "protected" keyword

Comment: this call?  $rs = $this->copy_folder($src, $dst);

Comment: It all runs ok on my env
using php 7. It still sounds like a permissions issue to me

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$src = './resources/instansi/default/';
$dst = './resources/instansi/';

function copy_folder($src, $dst) {
    $dir = @opendir($src);
    @mkdir($dst);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                copy_folder($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file); 
            }
            else {
                copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
 closedir($dir); 
}

copy_folder($src, $dst);
```

This is what I run without any problems. Which version of PHP are you using? How do you invoke `copy_folder`?

Comment: I can run that code and copy file but I can't copy folder inside a folder 'default'

Comment: can you show the files structure inside this 'default' folder?